# Time Machine for Business Intelligence (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, business-intelligence, timemachine

Currently I am developing a time machine for a open-source `Business Intelligence` software from scratch using PHP/MySQL.

My time-machine table is **used by all other tables** that need date info (such as orders, products, etc.) and they binding with `time_id`. So its MySQL table like this:

```
 time_id |  timestamp   | day  |  week  |  month  |  quarter
 1          1303689654    25      17       4         2
 2          1303813842    26      17       4         2
 ...
```

Order table binding like this:

```
order_id    |  time_id  ...
3123           2
...
```

**edit:** it's similar to [STAR SCHEMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

The problem is getting **TIME** (13:45) information as well. Usually I don't need this, but like orders, and sometimes a couple of tables need this HOUR/MINUTE infomation.

How can I solve this problem cleverly? I have a couple of solutions, but first i want to see your opinions..

Comment: Looks like a design flaw. making all other tables dependant on a time keeping table.. Do yourself a favor and replace time_id column with a simple timestamp. and add logic that parses that information to the individual components that you need.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this. Why not just use a `DATETIME` field? You can extract all the other info (day, week, month...) from that.

Comment: @netbrain - I use this table for a real-time analysis (BI). So it's like start schema. So I have to do this.

Comment: @Pekka - it's similar to star schema (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema)

Comment: @dino beytar: I think you don't get it, a date is just that, a date, not an object you would reference in a star schema. A starting point for a star schema would be the number of units sold on a specific date where the date is a timestamp or a datetime, and you store number of units and product id, which will in turn reference your products table, etc.

Comment: +1 @wimvds - I know, you right. I just gave an example. It's not exactly a star schema; more than star schema. Fact tables already use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply store timestamps in your other tables?

Or, if you want to keep the dates table, simply add a `TIME` field to your other tables which need it.

Comment: +1 According to your solution, I don't need `TIMESTAMP` in my time-machine table anymore. I mean, I can use `Ymd` like (20110403) instead of TIMESTAMP. Because if I need time, I can get it from other tables. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your timestamp correctly, you can probably just go:

```
echo date('H:i.s',1303689654);
```

**edit**

What are you trying to do? After re-reading your question you may be looking for the JOIN keyword in SQL ([brief tute](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/158_MySQL-LEFT-JOIN-and-RIGHT-JOIN-INNER-JOIN-and-OUTER-JOIN.html))

Comment: The problem is if you have more than one TIME in a day, so you have to create more than one timestamp for a day. But I shouldn't create more than one time for a day. So far, ThiefMaster's solution solve this problem.

Comment: Oh ok.  Typically timestamps are unique to an individual operation, so ThiefMaster's answer is quite appropriate. +1